# How to "give priority" to certain pattern instead of others in sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have this sed filter:

```
/.*[1-9][0-9][0-9] .*/{
        s/.*\([1-9][0-9][0-9] .*\)/\1/
}

/.*[1-9][0-9] .*/{
        s/.*\([1-9][0-9] .*\)/\1/
}

/.*[0-9] .*/{    # but this is always preferred/executed
        s/.*\([0-9] .*\)/\1/
}
```

The problem is that the first two are more restrictive, and they are not executed because the last third one is more "powerfult" because it includes the first two. Is there a way to make sed take the first two, with a "priority order"? Like

```
if the first matches
    do first things
elif the second matches
    do second things
elif the third matches
    do third things
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle

Comment: Is there a reason to spell out all different lengths of numbers instead of using something like`/.*[^1-9](([1-9][0-9]*|[0-9]) .*)/`? (though it requires ERE for the alternation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing what is your goal with those Regexp and not having a test data, what you need is a `t` branch that will cause your `sed` to branch to the end of the script and skip processing the rest of the code upon a successful substitution has been done.

```
sed '/regexp1/ s/do/things/; t
     /regexp2/ s/do/things/; t
     /regexp3/ s/do/things/ ' infile
```

Based on the command you used, you can also use `b` branch (unconditionally branch to the specified lable, or to the end of the script if label is omitted) `sed -e '/regex/{ s/do/things/; b' -e '}; ...'` too.

---

from 'man sed':

> t label
> If a s/// has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last t or
> T command, then branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.
>
> b label
> Branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.

Answer (score 2):

You are misinterpreting what is happening.  Sed always executes all patterns that match in order.  The problem is that the last pattern is re-editing what the first one did.

Also, a search pattern on s/// is redundant if it is identical to the match pattern, and you are not actually making different changes between these, so how would you know which one it ran?